# Passing value from one shell script to other

Tags: linux, shell, unix, aix

This is what I am trying

script1

```
var=10
sh -x script2 "$var"
```

script2

```
su - someuser << EOF
1
cd dir
echo "This is : $1 Error" >> somefile
2
2
0
exit
EOF
```

Everything in script2 is executing. When I am checking the file "somefile" the output is

```
This is :  Error
```

It is not showing the value of `var`

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine for me:

```
cat s1
var=10
sh -x /tmp/s2 "$var"

cat s2
su - my_id << EOF
id
echo $1
EOF

./s1
+ su - my_id
+ 0<<
id
echo 10
my_id's Password: <<< su is prompting for my password
uid=222(my_id) gid=222(my_group) ...
10
```

Because you are not adding the #!/bin/xxxxx I believe the default is to either execute /bin/sh or maybe what $SHELL is set to.  Check that both of those are what you expect.  Maybe add the explicit #!/bin/ksh (or #!/bin/sh ...) to make sure you are getting the shell that you want / expect.